# Running Laravel and WordPress on Same Server

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, laravel, ubuntu

I have WordPress installed on the root of my server, and I have a subfolder where Laravel is installed using the official Laravel installer. When I try to access using http://localhost/Laravel/ , I get a Http `500` Status Code

I tried the following:

```
sudo chown www-data:www-data  -R *
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

I have also set `Laravel/config/app.php` to:

- `'debug' => env('APP_DEBUG', true),` and
- `'url' => env('APP_URL', 'http://localhost/Laravel`

but I still get `500`.

---

I've also seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33939580/laravel-and-wordpress-on-same-server-domain), but in my case it is the other way around. I have Wordpress and Laravel as a subfolder as opposed to the case in this question.

Comment: What is the folder structure? Where is Laravel public folder and the rest of it.

Comment: And what's the detail of the error 500? You should have it in your Apache error log

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Apache or Nginx ? If Apache, you need to config your vhost file to serve Laravel from a sub-folder. Particularly, you need to configure that when `host.com/laravel` URI is requested, it should be served using `/home/host.com/laravel/public` directory (basically different root/home location).
You also need to use `mod_rewrite` to rewrite your URL requests to the sub-folder be served from `index.php` from above location (and also prettify URLs).

---

The above should work just fine since its done same way in Nginx, for which I have included a full example of how its conf file should look

Here is how I setup-ed my `location` block which is working for me perfectly:

```
location ^~ /facebookschedule {  
alias /home/netcans/facebookschedule/public;  
try_files $uri $uri/ @foobar;  

location ~ \.php {  
fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;  
fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;  
include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;  
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/wwww/facebookschedule/public/index.php;  
}  
}  

location @foobar {  
rewrite /facebookschedule/(.*)$ /facebookschedule/index.php?/$1 last;  
}
```

Source: http://shubhank.gaur.io/setup-laravel-5-in-subfolder-with-nginx/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and running these two commands fixed it:

```
sudo chmod 755 -R Laravel
chmod -R o+w Laravel/storage
```

This is assuming Laravel is the project name, otherwise just change it to whatever you named the project.